# Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions about using mobile apps?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions about using and troubleshooting mobile apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the Device, you can either ask on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) (for Android) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (for iOS), but check their help centers if such questions are on-topic there.